# How to pass data from model to a view in yii2

Tags: yii2

Here, I'm trying to design a payslip. I want to pass data from model right beside the text. like -

```
<p class="text-center">Pay Slip for the month of  </p>
```

The data will be fetched from the model and will be passed right beside "Pay Slip for the month of". Please help.

My Controller Action

```
public function actionPrintsalarystatement($id) {

        //$model =  Salary::find()->where(['s_id' => $id]);
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        $searchModel  = new SalarySearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        $data         = Salary::findOne($id);
        $content = $this->renderPartial('_printSalarystatement', ['model' => $model,'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,'searchModel'  => $searchModel,'data'=> $data]);
        $pdf = new Pdf([
            'mode'=> Pdf::MODE_UTF8,
            'format'=> Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
            'destination'=> Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
            //'destination' => Pdf::DEST_DOWNLOAD,
            'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
            // any css to be embedded if required
            'cssInline' => '.kv-heading-1{font-size:18px}', 
             // set mPDF properties on the fly
            'options' => ['title' => 'Print Payslip'],
             // call mPDF methods on the fly
            'methods' => [
                'SetHeader'=>['Private and Confidential'], 
                'SetFooter'=>['This Payslip is computer generated.'],
            ],
            'content'     => $content,


        ]);
        return $pdf->render();
        //return $this->render('_printSalarystatement', ['period' => 's_period']);
    }
```

_printSalarystatement.php

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\DetailView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model frontend\modules\salary\models\Salary */
//@var $model yii\base\Model
//@var $totaldays any

//$this->title = $model->s_id;
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Salaries', 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="salary-view">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <h1><strong><p class="text-center">PS Enterprise</p></strong></h1>
    <p class="text-center">Pay Slip for the month of s_period </p>


    <?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            's_id',
            's_date',
            's_period',
            's_empid',
            's_empname',
            's_workingdays',
            's_leave',
            's_holiday',
            's_wageperday',
            's_totalwage',
            's_ovthour',
            's_ovtrateperhour',
            's_ovtamount',
            's_tiffinworkingday',
            's_tiffinrateperday',
            's_wdtiffinamount',
            's_sundayworked',
            's_sundayrate',
            's_sundaytiffinamount',
            's_nightcount',
            's_nightallrate',
            's_nightallowance',
            's_convday',
            's_convrate',
            's_conveyanceamount',
            's_tiffinovtcount',
            's_tiffinovtrate',
            's_tiffinovtamount',
            's_incentivecount',
            's_incentiverate',
            's_incentive',
            's_totalearning',
            's_epf',
            's_esi',
            's_ptax',
            's_takehome',
        ],
    ]) ?>

</div>
```

By the controller action I get the following screen
[image]

What I want is to pass the period that is in the detailview to be shown after the line "Pay Slip for the month of ". mY question is how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass data from the `controller` `action` to the `view` you are rendering.

e.g lets hope you want to send `$name` variable from index action to view

Action will be like

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('index', ['name' => 'Tanmay']);
    }
```

Now the array you passed in the 2nd argument of `render` function is your variable list. All the keys will be treated as variable in the index view

The code for the index view will be

```
<h1>Welcome <?= $name; ?>
```

that is `['name' => 'Tanmay']`  will be converted to `$name` having value `'Tanmay'`

Hope this helps.
Thanks.

**Updated according to the updated Question:**

```
$content = $this->renderPartial('_printSalarystatement', [
'model' => $model,
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'searchModel'  => $searchModel,
'data'=> $data,
's_period' => $s_period // new variable added
]
);
```

in Controller

in view:

```
<p class="text-center">Pay Slip for the month of <?= $s_period; ?> </p>
```

Comment: Hi Unknown, I tried your solution but it ended up with Undefined variable. I'll adding my controller action and View file to make it clear. Please let me know what to do.

Comment: Thanks for updating question, also add what error are you getting

Comment: I've added my current position and what I am trying to do in the question.

Comment: getting error - Undefined variable: s_period in the controller action.

Comment: You have to initialize the $s_period variable in the Controller, assign it value

Comment: I'm not so sure how to do that. Please tell me.

Comment: I've tried to add $s_period in the Controller but still getting the same error. Please suggest what to do.

Comment: Also tried $s_period = Yii::$app->request->post('s_period'); in the controller action. But the period is not printing where it's needed. No error though.

Comment: var_dump($s_period) before sending it to View.

Comment: not getting any idea where to put it. Really stuck at this point.