# Object of class yii\db\ActiveQuery could not be converted to string

Tags: yii2

I'm trying to print data with the help of kartik mPDF. The detailview part is printing without any issue. But I need to print some lines along with the detailview. Now I need to pass data from the model to the view to be printed. I'm trying to do that but not so sure. Currently I'm getting error -

```
Object of class yii\db\ActiveQuery could not be converted to string
```

I may be wrong in my approach. But please tell me what correction needs to be done. This is the same question as - [How to pass data from model to a view in yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38318879/how-to-pass-data-from-model-to-a-view-in-yii2/38319827?noredirect=1#comment64266352_38319827)

Code of Controller Action -

```
public function actionPrintsalarystatement($id) {

        //Yii::app()->params['period'] = $period;
        //$s_period = $this->originalperiod;
        $period = Salary::find()->select(['s_period'])->where(['s_id' => $id])->asArray();
        //$period = Yii::$app->request->post('period');
        //$this->period = Salary::find()->select(['s_period'])->where(['s_id' => $id]);
        //$period = ArrayHelper::map(Salary::find($id)->select(['s_period'])->asArray()->all(), 's_period', 'period'),
        //$model =  Salary::find()->where(['s_period' => $period]);
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        $searchModel  = new SalarySearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        $data         = Salary::findOne($id);
        $content = $this->renderPartial('_printSalarystatement', [
            'model' => $model,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'searchModel'  => $searchModel,
            'data'=> $data,
            'period' => $period,

            ]);
        $pdf = new Pdf([
            'mode'=> Pdf::MODE_UTF8,
            'format'=> Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
            'destination'=> Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
            //'destination' => Pdf::DEST_DOWNLOAD,
            'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
            // any css to be embedded if required
            'cssInline' => '.kv-heading-1{font-size:18px}', 
             // set mPDF properties on the fly
            'options' => ['title' => 'Print Payslip'],
             // call mPDF methods on the fly
            'methods' => [
                'SetHeader'=>['Private and Confidential'], 
                'SetFooter'=>['This Payslip is computer generated.'],
            ],
            'content' => $content,

        ]);
        return $pdf->render();
        //return $this->render('_printSalarystatement', ['s_period' => $s_period]);

    }
```

Updated view.php

```
    <?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\DetailView;
use yii\web\View;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model frontend\modules\salary\models\Salary */
//@var $model yii\base\Model
//@var $totaldays any

//$this->title = $model->s_id;
//$this->period = $model->s_period;
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Salaries', 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="salary-view">


    <h1><strong><p class="text-center">My Company</p></strong></h1>
    <p class="text-center">Pay Slip for the month of <?php $model['s_period'];?> </p>

    <?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            's_id',
            's_date',
            's_period',
            's_empid',
            's_empname',
            's_workingdays',
            's_leave',
            's_holiday',
            's_wageperday',
            's_totalwage',
            's_ovthour',
        ],
    ]) ?>

</div>
```

What I'm trying to do -
[image]

Currently I'm getting
[image]

[image]

Comment: in which line you are getting this error?

Comment: Change `<p class="text-center">Pay Slip for the month of <?php echo $period;?> </p>` to `<p class="text-center">Pay Slip for the month of <?php echo $model->s_period;?> </p>` in your view file.

Comment: `$period = Salary::find()->select(['s_period'])->where(['s_id' => $id])->asArray()->one(); or ->all()`

Comment: You don't even need to get `$period` model in your controller. Your `$model` has already loaded the object. Just change the view and remove `$period = ...` ActiveQuery object from your controller.

Comment: @ThinkDifferent If I remove $period ActiveQuery object from my the controller action - I get error Undefined variable: period. But If I keep that and change my view file to - <?php echo $model->s_period;?> - the error is gone But I get output like "Pay Slip for the month of ". The period is not passed there. Please let me know what to do.

Comment: Obviously you have to remove it from the array() as well, which you are passing to the view using renderPartial. And in the view try `$model["s_period"]` rather than `$model->s_period`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment the $period object you are creating in controller as follows:

```
public function actionPrintsalarystatement($id) {

    //Yii::app()->params['period'] = $period;
    //$s_period = $this->originalperiod;
    //$period = Salary::find()->select(['s_period'])->where(['s_id' => $id])->asArray(); <=== Comment this line
    //$period = Yii::$app->request->post('period');
    //$this->period = Salary::find()->select(['s_period'])->where(['s_id' => $id]);
    //$period = ArrayHelper::map(Salary::find($id)->select(['s_period'])->asArray()->all(), 's_period', 'period'),
    //$model =  Salary::find()->where(['s_period' => $period]);
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $searchModel  = new SalarySearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $data         = Salary::findOne($id);
    $content = $this->renderPartial('_printSalarystatement', [
        'model' => $model,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'searchModel'  => $searchModel,
        'data'=> $data,
        //'period' => $period,  <=== Comment this as well

        ]);
    $pdf = new Pdf([
        'mode'=> Pdf::MODE_UTF8,
        'format'=> Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
        'destination'=> Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
        //'destination' => Pdf::DEST_DOWNLOAD,
        'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
        // any css to be embedded if required
        'cssInline' => '.kv-heading-1{font-size:18px}', 
         // set mPDF properties on the fly
        'options' => ['title' => 'Print Payslip'],
         // call mPDF methods on the fly
        'methods' => [
            'SetHeader'=>['Private and Confidential'], 
            'SetFooter'=>['This Payslip is computer generated.'],
        ],
        'content' => $content,

    ]);
    return $pdf->render();
    //return $this->render('_printSalarystatement', ['s_period' => $s_period]);

}
```

And in your view do the following:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\DetailView;
use yii\web\View;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model frontend\modules\salary\models\Salary */
//@var $model yii\base\Model
//@var $totaldays any

//$this->title = $model->s_id;
//$this->period = $model->s_period;
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Salaries', 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="salary-view">
<h1><strong><p class="text-center">My Company</p></strong></h1>
<p class="text-center">Pay Slip for the month of <?php echo $model['s_period'];?> </p>

<?php 
//Add these lines to see what you get in your $Model object
echo '<pre>'; print_r($model); echo '</pre>'; ?>

<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        's_id',
        's_date',
        's_period',
        's_empid',
        's_empname',
        's_workingdays',
        's_leave',
        's_holiday',
        's_wageperday',
        's_totalwage',
        's_ovthour',
    ],
]) ?>
```

Comment: I've tried as you said in this answer. Please have a look what output I'm getting. I've addded it in the question.

Comment: ok in your view do `print_r($model);` and see if you get the object values.

Comment: Not so sure where to put this code. Please tell me where to put it.

Comment: I have updated the answer, copy the lines in the view file and place it there in your file, then let me know what it displays.

Comment: I've added <?= print_r($model); ?> after <p class="text-center">Pay Slip for the month of <?php $model["s_period"];?> </p>. Got some output. I'm adding it in the question. Please have a look. I've added.

Comment: The value is there and `$model['s_period'];` should work, please check for any typo. It should work fine.

Comment: update your view in your question with the changes you made please.

Comment: Updated view in question.

Comment: You have missed echo in front of it either use `<?php echo $model['s_period']; ?>`    OR   `<?= $model['s_period']; ?>`

Comment: Ha ha ... Such an elementary mistake from me. It will be <?php echo $model['s_period'];?>. I missed the echo and finding it everywhere. Many many thanks @Think Different.

Comment: No worries. Happy to help